# Change blockchain data dir in Windows

Tags: datadir

I am running Windows Seven Enterprise: wondering if someone can advise me on the following. I had Ethereum Wallet on C:\ with only 12 GB free. I moved the Ethereum folder to E:\ and tried to setup the blockchaindir on E:\Ethereum Wallet using geth.exe --fast --cache=1024 datadir=E:\Etherdata

The proces starts downloading and shows the following error/warning:
[image]
but seems to continue happily

and then quits / hard stop after like 2 minutes without any clear warning at the following screen:
[image]

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55593/discussion-on-question-by-ethereumnoob-change-blockchain-data-dir-in-windows).

Answer (score 2):

Cant you just create a link and point your windows directory to the one in E drive

**Steps**

- Believe by default Ethereum directory is present here C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum
- Rename the C drive Ethereum directory to something else lets say
  Ethereum-Backup
- Open the command prompt in admin mode
- cd C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming
- mklink /D Ethereum E:\Ethereum
- Start geth client
- If everything works fine you can take the decision to remove the Ethereum-Backup directory

**Second Part**

You can check the size of which chaindata folder as listed below is getting updated or not. You can check the latest file modified date. I believe you might be in the main network (i.e. homestead) due to which it is taking long time to sync.

Also check which folder size is increasing.

**Main Network Data Folder**
C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\chaindata

**Test Network Data Folder**
C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\geth\chaindata

You can always start the getch client with a new genesis config file

geth init genesis.json

Help for creating a private Ethereum network
https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html

By the way if your intention is to practice Ethereum then you can use Testrpc. Testrpc basically simulates Ethereum block chain. You don't have to wait long for your deployments or synching issues. In addition Parity has developed a new testnet named Kovan which in similar lines much stable and good for developers.

Testrpc - https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc
Kovan - https://github.com/kovan-testnet/proposal

Comment: Thank you @Susmit.  I am trying this now as we speak , created the symbolic link, that seemed to work, Geth is running now too, does it matter when I fire up Ethereum Wallet at this point? Thanks!! PS: What I dont get, i just fired up Ethereum wallet in parallel with Geth still synching/running, and it still seems that Ethereum wallet is starting a separate synch process....am I missing something here?

Comment: Glad it helped. Is it possible that mist is hitting main network and direct instance of geth hitting testnet? Secondly have you confirmed from your task manager that you have two instances of geth running when you start mist?

Comment: Checked Taskmanager: Geth only seems to be running once (btw, since I started it, it still running hasnt stopped yet). I dont know how to tell if Mist is htting main and direct geth is hitting test (sure dont hope so, its been running for 18 hours or so now)

Comment: Folder seems to be filled with 13 GB only so far...(does this mean it will run until the 90GB is completed? ) and how will the Ethereum Wallet know where to look for the data?

Comment: So that does mean that only single instance of geth is running and mist has not started a new geth instance.

What is the command you used to start geth. Did you apply --testnet as that is used to run the Ropsten testnet. In Mist app under Develop->Network menu you can see what network is selected. Also next to the Send menu it should list the network name on which it is running.

In testnet I think it should be at max 16 or 17 GB of data.

Comment: I can only see one geth in my processlist. If i try to select Develop->Network then both options (Test and Main network) are greyed out, also Develop>Ethereum Node > Geth 1.5.9 (Go) is greyed out. command I used to run geth did not include --testnet. I am really in doubt if this is going well, since I still dont know what to do if the process ever finishes...What confuses me is that the progress is not reflected in the Ethereum Wallet, should that be the case? I was expecting to see x% finished or something, instead I see: 25 peers, 3.384440 blocks and then a clock pictogram/ second timer

Comment: Is there no way for me to import my account setting in a different online Ethereum wallet or something?

Comment: Have modified the above answer as it was not fitting here. Please have a look

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I should clarify. While setting up the Ethereum wallet i took the address before it was synched and ordered Ethercoins worth 100 dollars. The payment was accepted and sent over to the address I provided, however the geth process has been runing for over 3 days continously now, and I see the data in E:\Ethereum\geth is now on 13,5GB, I dont thinkthis is going to work out for me, cant I export the account and import it into lets say a coinbase ETH account and receive the Ethercoins there?

Comment: Also, I am very unsure to kill the geth process now, because I'm throwing away three days of potential synching...:(

Comment: To be frank I won't ask you to perform few experimental things as I am new to Ethereum as well and don't want any suggestions which may harm your real Ethers. I would in that case ask you to find some more experienced person who can give more matured inputs in this regard.

Comment: Thank you, I have given up, killed Geth, it wasnt going anywhere...I have put in over 20 hours now...getting frustrated and tired of not getting anywhere with Ethereum Wallet...